# I'm getting an error in python while installing the dlib library

Tags: python, cmake, pycharm, face-recognition, dlib

when I try to install dlib library via pycharm in python, I get this error. I updated pip but it didn't improve, I tried it in different python versions and I still get the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN56b.png)

I updated cmake, I updated pip, python 3.11

Answer (score 1):

Probably you don't have [C++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) installed. Try installing it before cmake. In general, there is a good [guide](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10-57348ba1117f)  for this

Comment: yes, I didn't install anything related to c++. Is there any resource you can recommend or can you briefly describe it?

Comment: see [answer], which suggests not to answer poorly written questions (see [ask])

Answer (score 1):

try these steps:

1. Install CMake: Ensure that you have CMake installed on your system. If not, you can download and install it from the official website: https://cmake.org/install/
2. Install Visual Studio (Windows): If you are using Windows, make sure you have Visual Studio with C++ support installed. click [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) to download
3. Update pip: Ensure that you have the latest version of pip installed.

   pip install --upgrade pip

When done updating, try installing dlib again.

If you still encounter issues, you can try installing dlib from the [master branch](https://github.com/davisking/dlib) on GitHub by following the instructions in the README file.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the steps, I hope it works.

Comment: see [answer], which suggests not to answer poorly written questions (see [ask])

Comment: sure hope it works